# Array in contract is pre-filled with random accounts

Tags: solidity, etherscan, testing

Hi all I have a problem with my contract, [have a look](https://github.com/DieKant/smartcontract-lottery/blob/main/contracts/Lottery.sol)

I use a players array to save every account that calls the enter function, the enter function is the only function that pushes accounts into the array and I have a CatchPlayerEntering event to see which account it's entering, I also have a PlayersArray event to see the content of the players array

When I test the contract with this [python test](https://github.com/DieKant/smartcontract-lottery/blob/main/tests/test_lottery_integration.py) and call the PlayersArray event in the constructor 2 random accounts are present into the players array but I didn't call the enter function and my CatchPlayerEntering event  is not triggered by them

Can someone explain to me what it's causing this please? I'm really confused

Image of the event log form etherscan
[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Parameters in events are encoded using [ABI spec](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.9/abi-spec.html).

To correctly read them you have to use a decoder.

For example

```
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002
00000000000000000000000019fefe4f8aa9f10e3da680a8645e28d548d5d670
00000000000000000000000019fefe4f8aa9f10e3da680a8645e28d548d5d670
```

It's an array of two elements.

- `0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020` it's the offset where data start
- `0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002` is the array length: 2
- `00000000000000000000000019fefe4f8aa9f10e3da680a8645e28d548d5d670` first item
- `00000000000000000000000019fefe4f8aa9f10e3da680a8645e28d548d5d670` second item